# Wicket: Can I use a modal Panel with a AjaxFallbackButton?

Tags: java, wicket

I have 2 inputs. When I press a button(AjaxFallbackButton), those inputs are saved into database.

If one of the input is greater than 10, when I press the button, I want to show a modal panel, for asking the user if is the sure about his option. But the modal component is not appearing. Any thoughts?

```
 @Override
     public void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

  if (input < 10) { //save to database
} else {
         AskingDialogPanel panel = new AskingDialogPanel("content",
       new ResourceModel("asking.title"),
       new ResourceModel("asking.message")) {
      @Override
      public void onOkClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
       super.onOkClick(target);

                                                    //save to database
       modalWindow.close(target);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

       super.onCancelClick(target);
       modalWindow.close(target);
      }
     };
                                    panel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
                target.addComponent(panel);
                modalWindow.setContent(panel);
                modalWindow.show(target);
}
```

Comment: More complete code might help with diagnosing this.

There's definitely code in there that you shouldn't need (see my comment on Tim's answer), but from what's shown I don't see what's making it fail to show the modal window.

Have you used a debugger, debugging logs or tests to verify that the else clause here is actually reached?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation for the [AjaxRequestTarget](http://wicket.apache.org/docs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxRequestTarget.html).

> A component whose markup needs to be
>   updated should be added to this target
>   via
>   AjaxRequestTarget#addComponent(Component)
>   method. Its body will be rendered and
>   added to the envelope when the target
>   is processed, and refreshed on the
>   client side when the ajax response is
>   received.

I'm not sure if I remember this correctly (I've had trouble implementing the correct refresh behavior previously), but I believe you could only `addComponent` components that were previously added to the page, but not rendered / invisible. These will than be updated and/or their visibility re-evaluated.

I could be wrong however.. Does the above work if you substitute a normal Label for the AskingDialogPanel? (Just to verify I'm talking out the wrong end ;))

Comment: You shouldn't actually need the target.addComponent(panel) or the panel.setOutputMarkupId(true) at all, as these are handled inside the ModalWindow code.